# How can i split a column of list in different rows in bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap with reactjs. I am getting data from a list of the array, and that data should be display on screen but when I tried I get a list of data in the vertical direction. I want to make Only 4 element in a row and then it should make another row like buttons in the calculator. I tried to do that using bootstrap grid but it did not work.

This is my code. Here I mapped through and passed data to different component

```
PadButtons = this.props.currentPadBank.map((drumObj, i, padBankArr) => {
      return (
        <PadButton
          key={padBankArr[i].id}
          clipId={padBankArr[i].id}
          clip={padBankArr[i].url}
          keyTrigger={padBankArr[i].keyTrigger}
          keyCode={padBankArr[i].keyCode}
        />
      );
```

Then here I display the data

```
<div id="display">
        <button
          className="drum-pad btn btn-secondary btn-lg"
          onClick={this.playSound}
          id={this.props.clipId}
        >
          <audio id={this.props.keyTrigger} src={this.props.clip} />
          {this.props.keyTrigger}
        </button>
      </div>
```

[This is my codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/freecodecamp-project-drummachine-gusg3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes

In Drumpad.js

```
<div className="container">
    <div className="row">{PadButtons}</div>
</div>
```

In PadButton.js

```
<div id={`display-${this.props.keyTrigger}`} className="col-sm-3">
    <button
      className="drum-pad"
      onClick={this.playSound}
      id={this.props.clipId}>
      <audio id={this.props.keyTrigger} src={this.props.clip} />
      {this.props.keyTrigger}
    </button>
</div>
```

See updated https://codesandbox.io/s/7ymd7

Basically, you had to add `col-sm-3` class on the element that is being repeated and it must be inside a wrapper `row` div.